# Firebase can not change displayName ,displayName is null on every way

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Can't add I  more user information with `await FirebaseAuth.instance
 .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);` function?

> part of `signup.dart` file:

```
 String _email, _password, _name;

  final formkey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();`

  Future<void> registered() async {
    if (formkey.currentState.validate()) {
      formkey.currentState.save();
      try {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
        Firestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .document(firebaseUser.uid)
            .setData({"name": _name});
        await firebaseUser.reload();
        firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
        print(
            "${firebaseUser.uid},${firebaseUser.email},${firebaseUser.displayName} , $_password this user has been created-----");
      } catch (e) {
        print("${e.message} message--------------------------------------");
      }
    } else {
      print("somthing went wrong");
    }
  }
```

I have tried many way to do this but still i have no result

Answer (score 1):

You are saving data in Firestore, and trying to get the name from Firebase Auth. Those are two services. Instead of trying to use firestore, what you could is,

```
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    var userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
    userUpdateInfo.displayName = _name;
    firebaseUser.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
    await firebaseUser.reload();
    firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
```

Answer (score -1):

After creating the account using the method **.createUserWithEmailAndPassword** pass the value of the user to another class by

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //user object based on firebase
  User _userFromFirebase(FirebaseUser user){
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid):null;
  }

Future loginWithEmailAndPass(String email,String password)async{
    try{
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebase(user);
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Pass the value of user to a new class by creating a new dart file

```
class User{
  final String uid;

  User({this.uid});
}
```

Include that dart file in the home page for the user name.

Refer this tutorial for guidance.
https://youtu.be/Jy82t4IKJSQ?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC

Comment: i didn't get what i exactly to do.there isn't something like creating user with more fields in that video.

Comment: Thats a playlist.... you can skip some of the content in it to go to your part...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfA3NWDBPZ4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC